# Using AngularJs, how can I ng-hide an element when the data in a child's sub-collection is filtered out?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to display a list of conference sessions by day and time, such that there is a header for the day, followed by a header for each timeslot during the day, followed by a list of sessions scheduled for that timeslot.

The sessions also have filters enabled so that the user can filter based on a number of properties, such as title or category.

What I'm trying to accomplish is have the day and/or time headers hide if the user's filter removes all of the sessions in that timeslot or day.  I'm currently able to hide the timeslot header (since the sessions are a direct child collection on that object), but am not able to find a way to hide the day header if all of the sessions for that day are filtered out (since the sessions are not immediately available on the object).

Here is an example of the HTML I'm using with the Angular tags:

```
<article ng-repeat="sessionDayGroup in ScheduledSessions" >
    <div><h2>{{ sessionDayGroup.Day }}</h2></div>

    <div ng-repeat="timeslotGroup in sessionDayGroup.TimeSlots">
        <div ng-if="(timeslotGroup.Sessions | filter: { Category: sessions.categoryFilter}).length != 0" >          
            <h2>{{ timeslotGroup.Time }}</h2>
        </div>

        <div ng-repeat="session in timeslotGroup.Sessions | filter: { Category: sessions.categoryFilter}">              
            <div><h3>{{ session.Title }}</h3></div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</article>
```

Note that the ng-if attribute on the timeslot `h3` header successfully hides the timeslot header if there are no sessions after applying the filter.  I need a similar ng-if statement (or other approach) to apply to the sessionDayGroup.Day `h2` element.

Here's an example of the JSON data that feeds the ScheduleSessions:

```
ScheduledSessions =>
    {
        Day => "Sun 8/17",
        TimeSlots => 
            {
                Time => "8:00 am",
                Session => 
                    { Title = "title 1", Category = "fun"},
                    { Title = "title 2", Category = "fun"},
                    { Title = "title 3", Category = "boring"},
            },
            {
                Time => "9:00 am",
                Session => 
                    { Title = "title 4", Category = "fun"},
                    { Title = "title 5", Category = "fun"},
                    { Title = "title 6", Category = "fun"},
            },
    },
    {
        Day => "Mon 8/18",
        TimeSlots => 
            {
                Time => "8:00 am",
                Session => 
                    { Title = "title 7", Category = "fun"},
                    { Title = "title 8", Category = "fun"},
                    { Title = "title 9", Category = "fun"},
            },
            {
                Time => "9:00 am",
                Session => 
                    { Title = "title 10", Category = "fun"},
                    { Title = "title 11", Category = "fun"},
                    { Title = "title 12", Category = "fun"},
            },
    },
```

Comment: You can create a custom filter that determines if there are any time slots for that day present based on the filter set. You can also create a filtered `ScheduledSessions` array whose contents change when the filter changes. That is, rather than supplying the entire array, supply a filtered array yourself and not rely on AngularJS filters - keep an eye on the filter set (through `$watch`) and then update the array based on the filter set.

Comment: @callmekatootie Using a custom filter was how I ended up doing this -- thanks!  If you'll submit that as an answer (instead of as a comment), I'll mark that as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom filter for this.

The way you define your custom filter is similar to a scope function:

```
$scope.myCustomFilter = function (record) {
    //Your custom filter logic here
};
```

This custom filter function is called each time for each record present in the loop array.
The `record` parameter contains this single record details.

Your custom filter function is expected to return a boolean value indicating whether the record should be shown or not - that is, whether the record should be included in the loop or not.

Alternatively, you can use a filtered array instead of using an array that contains all the elements. Keep a watch on the filters and when they change, update the filtered array.